# Linux ODBC driver for ProvideX database

Tags: linux, database, odbc, driver

I'm assigned to find a solution for an issue with connecting proprietary ProvideX database to a running web application developed on a OSX platform using PHP language. What I've figured is that if there will be a possible way for querying data from ProvideX, The web app could pull data and update itself with live data. ODBC is what I found as an effective and possible solution. 
The question is that, is there any Linux ODBC driver for provideX so the web API would be able to communicate to ProvideX database? I know that there's one for windows platform since ProvideX has been designed to work with windows systems. 
Any thought or writeup I could go over to find out more on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to go strictly through the ODBC driver. It works nice if you're just looking at the data in an ODBC compliant application or service, but for web applications PxPlus offers a different way to access the database. Look for PxPlus web server, which may or may not be included in your installation.